# Remove max and min duplicate of a list of number

Tags: python

I would like to remove ONLY the maximum and minimum duplicate of a list of
numbers. Example: (**1 1 1** 4 4 5 6 **8 8 8**) Result: (**1** 4 4 5 6
**8**)

How do I combine max() min() function with `list(set(x))`?

Or is there another way?

```
s = raw_input("Please Input a series of numbers")
numbers = map(int, s.split())

numbers.remove(max(numbers))
numbers.remove(min(numbers))
average = sum(numbers)/float(len(numbers))
print average
```

Comment: Is the list always sorted?

Comment: Must order be maintained?

Comment: Too many open questions to OP

Comment: hint. you'll need a loop. I'll post a proper answer if this gets reopened maybe. For future reference people here don't like "eat my problem" kinds of questions. You should always show that you have made an effort to solve it yourself. Show an attempt, show expected versus actual results, give a theory if you have one

Comment: Your example data is sorted, and this allows a different (and simpler) approach than if the data is not sorted: remove the right numbers of elements from the front and back. So it's probably a good idea to say whether or not the data can be relied on to be sorted, and if not whether the order of the result needs to be the same as the order of the input.

Answer (score 1):

```
s = raw_input("Please Input a series of numbers")
numbers = map(int, s.split())
# numbers = [1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 5, 6, 8, 8, 8]
mi = min(numbers)
ma = max(numbers)
b = [mi] + [x for x in numbers if x != mi and x != ma] + [ma]
```

Comment: Please improve this answer by adding an explanation

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fairly general solution to the problem using some `itertools` functions. That solution will collapse a repetition of min and max values into a single value wherever that repetition may appear:

```
from itertools import groupby,starmap,chain
#first we count the sequence length for each group of number in the list
c=[[number,len(list(seq))] for number,seq in groupby(numbers)]
print(c)

#we collapse the repetitions only for min and max
for group in c:
    if group[0] == min(numbers) or group[0]== max(numbers):
        group[1]=1       
print(c)

#we put back the list together
numbers=list(chain(*starmap(lambda x,n : [x]*n, c)))
print(numbers)
```

Example output:

```
>>>numbers=[1,1,1,4,4,5,6,8,8,8]
[1, 4, 4, 5, 6, 8]
>>>numbers=[4,4,1,1,1,5,6,8,8,8]
[4, 4, 1, 5, 6, 8]
#edge case if there are multiple groups of min :
>>>numbers=[4,4,1,1,1,5,1,1,1,6,8,8,8]
[4, 4, 1, 5, 1, 6, 8]
```